# why onPictureInPictureModeChanged method is not working?

Tags: android, kotlin, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I am trying to implement Picture in Picture in my app
It is perfectly entering in PiP mode.

The problem is that the override method onPictureInPictureModeChanged method is not called when entering PIP mode.

My onPictureInPictureModeChanged method is showing an error

> override method should call super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged

My minSdk 24 and targetSdk 33

```
private fun pictureInPictureMode(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        Log.d(TAG, "pictureInPictureMode: Supports PIP")
        val aspectRatio = Rational(videoView.width, videoView.height)
        pictureInPictureParamsBuilder!!.setAspectRatio(aspectRatio).build()
        enterPictureInPictureMode(pictureInPictureParamsBuilder!!.build())
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your device doesn't supports PIP", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}


override fun onPictureInPictureModeChanged(
    isInPictureInPictureMode: Boolean,
    newConfig: Configuration?
) {
    super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode, newConfig)
    if (isInPictureInPictureMode){
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureInPictureModeChanged: Entered PIP")
        pipButton.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    else{
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureInPictureModeChanged: Exited PIP")
        pipButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```